# How to execute query based on passed operators <,= by param using Stored Procedures?

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure(SP) where one of it's param passes the operator.
The operator can be: `<=`, `>=`, `=`

How can I use this in the query?

How the operators are passed is not built yet, it can be string represented `<=` or by using a custom code `1`, `2` or `3`. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're doing something strange.

However, you can pass the operator as a string, and use it inside your SP to create a prepared statement.

Comment: I know sounds awkward but I have to stick to this single SP, and modify it to suit the different options. And one of the filters is a value and the operator too is a filter option.